# I need to send a mail from my custom module if there is any update in webform

Tags: webforms

I have to implement a custom module where I need to send a mail if there is any update in webform. I cannot use Rules Module.

For example, there is an option field(drop down) in webform, where value of option field is changed from name_1 to name_2. I need send mail to name_2.

So, what kind of Hook function i need to use? should I use Hook_webform_element_alter() or Hook_webform_option_alter() or not both? Please do help me. Thank you.

Comment: Webforms do not necessarily have prior values. Do you mean if someone edits a submitted or draft form?

Comment: if someone editted submitted form

Comment: You should specify your drupal version and your webform version

Comment: Drupal version 8 and webform version 6.1.3